# Puppeteer Typescript : Fails with errors when transpilling

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

Source of the problem : I can't use Javascript as it is because Firebase Functions Node.Js version doesn't support Async/Await yet. So I put this in Typescript and now are trying to transpile to commonJs.

Then I do.

`tsc -p config.json`, which then produces these erros.

```
../../../node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/auth.d.ts(5,22): error TS2420: Class 'UserRecordMetadata' incorrectly implements interface 'UserMetadata'.
  Property 'lastSignedInAt' is missing in type 'UserRecordMetadata'.
../../../node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore.d.ts(17,19): error TS2694: Namespace 'admin' has no exported member 'firestore'.
```

Also, using `Firebase Serve -only-functions` worked ok using Vanilla Js, only started failing on Deploy, another thing, when running the vanilla script using `node getTags.js`, runs with no issues.

So figure probably it's my tsconfig? Please help.

**TSCONFIG.JSON**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "files": [
        "getTags.ts"
    ]
}
```

**Typescript.**

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

function getTitle() {
    const ogSelector: any = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:title"]');
    if (ogSelector) {
        return ogSelector.content;
    }

    const imgSelector: any = document.querySelector('[itemprop="name"]');
    if (imgSelector) {
        return imgSelector.text;
    }
    if (document.querySelector('title')) {
        return document.querySelector('title').text;
    }
    return window.location.href; // Print URL as a fallback
}

function getDescription() {
    const ogDesc: any = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:description"]');
    if (ogDesc) {
        return ogDesc.content;
    }

    const descSelector: any = document.querySelector('[itemprop="description"]');
    if (descSelector) {
        return descSelector.text;
    }

    const nameDescSelector: any = document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]');
    if (nameDescSelector) {
        return nameDescSelector.content;
    }

    return document.body.innerText.substring(0, 180) + '...';
}

function getImage() {
    const ogImgSelector: any = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:image"]');
    if (ogImgSelector) {
        return ogImgSelector.content;
    }

    const imgTagSelector: any = document.querySelector('[itemprop="image"]');
    if (imgTagSelector) {
        return imgTagSelector.text;
    }

    return null;
}

exports.getTags = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://itunes.apple.com/za/album/my-dear-melancholy/1363309866?app=music&ign-itsct=1363309866-1363309866&ign-itscg=0176&ign-mpt=uo%3D4');

        const title = await page.evaluate(getTitle);
        const description = await page.evaluate(getDescription);
        const image = await page.evaluate(getImage) || await page.screenshot({ path: 'temp.png' });

        browser.close();

        const tags = {
            title,
            description,
            image,
        };
        console.log("Tags " + JSON.stringify(tags));
        res.send("Done Tags :: " + tags);
    })();
});
```

Comment: Not a solution, but why the `: any` on so many variables? You may as well not use typescript at that point

Comment: Puppeteer is known not to work on Cloud Functions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667933/running-puppeteer-code-in-firebase-cloud-functions?rq=1

Comment: @DougStevenson, Ok that's completely disappointing from Firebase, anyway I can still get meta tags another way on cloud functions? Something that is supported?

Answer (score 1):

When using TS and puppeteer I seem to find transpiling down to ES5 seems to work better for me when using Mocha (ok not deployed to Firebase), but its worth a shot.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        //"target": "esnext",
        "target": "es5", //needed for node!
        "declaration": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015", "dom"
        ]        
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```