# Unable to deploy a firebase function using Typescript and Puppeteer

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

This is my first time working with [Firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). I can make my function work locally, getting the **scraped** data that I want with Puppeteer. However I can not deploy this function to Firebase, because of the following error:

```
 Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file lib/index.js can't be 
    loaded. Is there a syntax error in your code? Detailed stack trace: TypeError 
    [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at promisify (internal/util.js:214:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/extract-zip/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/BrowserFetcher.js:21:17)
```

The index.ts file where I export my function is the following:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import urls from "./data/urls";
import scraper from "./scraper";

admin.initializeApp();

exports.data = functions
  .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 30, memory: "1GB" })
  .region("europe-west1")
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const products = await Promise.all(urls.map((url) => scraper(url)));
      res.send(products);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
`
```

**Scraper file**

```
export default async function scraper(url: string) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitFor(3000);

  const title = await page.$eval(
    "#productTitle",
    (el) => (el as HTMLElement).innerText
  );
  const image = await page.$eval("#landingImage", (img) =>
    img.getAttribute("src")
  );
  let price;

  if ((await page.$("#price_inside_buybox")) !== null) {
    price = await page.$eval(
      "#price_inside_buybox",
      (el) => (el as HTMLElement).innerText
    );
  } else {
    price = "precio segunda";
  }

  const res = {
    title,
    image,
    price,
  };

  await browser.close();
  return res; // TODO somehow get the promotions
}
```

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "deploy this function"?
Are you using [page.evaluate](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.0.1&show=api-pageevaluatepagefunction-args) or [Page.exposeFunction](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.0.1&show=api-pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction), or [page.addScriptTag](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.0.1&show=api-pageaddscripttagoptions) ?¿

Comment: By deploy I mean uploading the function to firebase cloud: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: I am using page.$eval

Comment: I've just started experimenting with firebase functions as well and ran into the same problem. For me, merely adding 

    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

into the functions/index.js file causes the same stacktrace (even if not used) when I deploy my functions. I, too, like to know the cause for this error.

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue. Originally it seemed puppeteer support was only added with Node 8 (which I am using), but all other indications are that it should work.

this discussion 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667933/running-puppeteer-code-in-firebase-cloud-functions starts with deployment to Firebase functions but then talks about Cloud functions.

I have logged a report ticket with Firebase

Comment: @MariusB Is it possible for me to get a link to that report ticket? I might be able to add to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and solved it by reverting back to puppeteer@2.1.1

If you don't use 3.x.x specific feature, this is the workaround until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Works for me.

Comment: Joshua Okpako's response below should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but I realized that it is because puppeteer no longer uses node 8 from version 3 onward as described on their version 3.0.0 release https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/v3.0.0

To fix the issue, you need to change your node version in the package.json file in your functions folder. You need to change it from this

```
"engines": {
"node": "8"
 },
```

to

```
"engines": {
"node": "10"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Berry, that worked for me. We will wait until the issue with version 3 is fixed.